# Is there any way to generate perpendicular faces while deforming geometry?

Tags: geometry

Weird question probably, but this is the part where I elaborate!

Lets say I have a plane and subdivide it with 4 so that the plane is now a grid of 5x5 faces.

Is there some magical script or perhaps built-in way to have it so that when I move the central face, perpendicular faces are generated to prevent surrounding faces from deforming? Pic attached. Left portion is normal behavior, right portion is desired behavior. Which would occur regardless of what face is extruded.

So basically when any given face is moved, rather than the adjacent faces being deformed, perpendicular ones are generated.

[image: Or do I need to do it manually forever?]

Comment: Blender is not Sketchup... Just select the face press **E** and move the mouse in the direction you want to extrude.